# Is there a .NET Tool/Add-in available which allows you to easily rearrange the order of Regions, Subs, Functions, and Member Variables in a Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, add-in

I'm looking for a .NET Add-in that reads in the contents of the Current Document window, lists the header declaration of all Regions, Subs, Functions, and Module Level Variables, and provides a simple Move Up/Move Down buttons to rearrange their order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that the "File Structure Window" provided by the [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) add-in provides most of the features you are looking for.  However, it is part of a comprehensive refactoring add-in and this may not suit you.

Comment: You can also use automatic member ordering feature of Code Cleanup, which covers (almost) all features of Regionerate and other plugins and adds more.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't yet used it (as I usually just code in the regions myself, or wait until I'm doing other refactoring on an inherited project), but [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/) looks good.

Comment: Thanks, but Regionerate is not quite what I'm looking for.  I really don't use Regions that often, but the tool would have to move Regions as a unit (or even better, allow moving members within a Region).  I also do a lot of VB.NET coding and this only supports C#.

Comment: Interesting problem to have ... I don't know of any offhand. Might make for a fun experiment with VS add-ons.

Odd that Regionerate is C# only; the #region syntax is identical aside from casing and VB requiring quoted strings.

Comment: I use Regionerate, and its very customizable and works pretty good.  I think the OP is looking for something that doesn't exist, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an automatic member organisation plugin that will work with [DXCore](http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/). You can also see Mark Miller developing this plugin in dnrTV.

http://dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showID=5